# Display name for OneNote Notebook is not shared across computers

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2010, microsoft-onenote-2013

When creating a new Notebook in Microsoft OneNote, I was trying to change the `Display name` from "Notebook" to something a little more descriptive.

By right-clicking the name of the Notebook, and selecting "Properties", I can easily change the display name and color of the Notebook for myself. However, no one else on my team can see these changes.

This is probably the desired default behavior ([according to this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnguin/2014/03/27/onenote-tip-change-the-notebook-display-name-to-save-screen-real-estate/)). **Is there a way to override the default behavior, and sync changes to display name and color with others who share the same Notebook?**

[image: onenote notebook properties]

Using Office Professional 2013. File format is "OneNote 2010-2013 notebook format".

Comment: There's no built-in way I know of. You could break out process monitor and see if there's a registry key you could change.

Comment: Pretty sure you are correct about this being the desired default behavior.  To force a name change across all users of the notebook, you have to change the name of the notebook itself at its actual saved location.  However, doing this will break the connection for anyone using the book so they will have to re-add the notebook after doing so.